# Group and ungroup objects in Office Powerpoint Online?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any way to group/ungroup objects when editing a presentation in Powerpoint Online? I only have access to the online version of Office 365 at work, but it is a *pain* to have to move the objects one by one if they can't be grouped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there a lot of different features in Office 365 PowerPoint than Microsoft PowerPoint 2010? Grouping in 2010 is just selecting the objects and pressing ctrl + G and ctrl + shift + G to ungroup.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this question.  It appears that this feature is in fact missing from Powerpoint Online, which is explicitly what is being asked here.  Responding with a passive aggressive image telling the poster to search google, or providing answers for other versions of Powerpoint isn't very helpful.  https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/270149-powerpoint-online/suggestions/18886765-support-grouping-and-ungrouping-of-objects

Comment: This is a huge missing feature in Powerpoint 365!!!!!!

Comment: @AndrewH I don't know if it's a lot but it's certainly some of the most important features that are missing.  For me this is the second in two days of using it: (1) grouping objects and (2) aligning objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try ctrl+G and Ctrl+Shift+G to group and ungroup respectively. These options are available in the ribbon too.

Comment: Hi sarath, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: This doesn't work in PowerPoint Online.